# Search functionality for complete website - yii

Tags: yii

I want to add search functionality in my website which will be able to search complete website (like user profiles , posts and etc )

I have created tab (User , Post , Comments ) on search page , and on each tab click I have called default Search() function of each model and it is displaying complete records.Now I got stuck in specific searching like If user type something in search box so on three of tabs only that thing should be display which have that keyword from search box.

Here is  my code :

in my SiteController :

this controller is for main search box which is in `main.php`

```
public function actionSearch() {

           $model = new TblUserProfile;

        $this->render('search'
                ,  array('model'=>$model)

);


//        } 

        }
```

Then in profile controller :

```
public function actionProfileSearch() {


        $model = new TblUserProfile;


        $this->layout = 'null';
        $this->render('/tblUserProfile/profilesearch', array('model' => $model));
    }
```

then same thing in the post and comment controller !

### and this is my search page (site/search) :

```
<?php 
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiTabs', array(
    'tabs'=>array(
        'People'=>array('ajax'=>array('/tblUserProfile/profilesearch','view'=>'/tblUserProfile/profilesearch')),

         'Blogs'=> array('ajax'=>array('/tblPost/postsearch','view'=>'/tblPost/postsearch')),


        'Comments'=> array('ajax'=>array('/tblComments/commentsearch','view'=>'/tblComments/commentsearch','search'=>'omer')),
    ),
    'options'=>array(
        'collapsible'=>true,
        'selected'=>0,
    ),
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'style'=>'width:900px;'
    ),
));
?>
```

Now I want help to get value from search box and in each search I can make only that keyword search not complete, How can I do this ?

Comment: See http://www.sphider.eu/about.php

Comment: I want it to be done in yii. please give provie solutions in yii contect

Answer (score 4):

You can look at a third party service such as [google site search](http://www.google.co.za/enterprise/search/products_gss.html)

But if you are wanting a custom solution it can get quite complex. One of the ways to do it is to create an index database table. The structure of this table will depend on what it needs to store.

The concept behind this is that any time data is inserted into any of the other "indexable" tables (user profiles , posts etc...), an index will be created in the index table, which will store:

- The searchable text (the content that the users search query will
  compared against)
- The type of the content (user profile/post etc...)
- The URL of the content (or some reference to a method of linking to the relevant content)

This way, when a user searches, you simply compare the query to the index, and return the results. You can even include filters for types (example: a drop down where the user can select the type of content to search)